# Хотел сделать программу на Python которая перебирает все возможные значения функции 3n + 1, и тут ошибка о переполнении стэка

Tags: python, stackoverflow

Вот код:

```
def f(n):
        n = 3*n-1
        return n

def f2(n):
        n = n/2
        return n

number = 15
while True:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = f2(number) 
    else:
        number = f(number)
print(number)
```

Comment: Вы что-то не договариваете, показанный код в принципе не может переполнять стек, потому что в нём отсутствует рекурсия. А ваш цикл `while True` будет вечным, потому что нигде нет условия выхода из него

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last) - вот такая ошибка, разве это не переполнение стека?

Comment: Нет, это всего лишь первая строка-заголовок из стандартной печати текущего стека

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за ответ

Comment: ну и деление лучше делать целочисленное. Но это так. А `while True:` стоит менять на `while number != 1:`

Comment: У вас цикл по кругу будет в итоге бегать: 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2...

Comment: в этом и заключается смысл функции 3n+1: любое целое число рано или поздно придет к циклу 4-2-1-4-2-1